# C++ assignment operator default return

Tags: c++, visual-studio, return-value, assignment-operator

When defining the operator assignment for a class in C++ I noticed that you don't need to return *this. I tested this on Visual Studio 2012, Visual Studio 2010 with warning level 4 and had no errors or warnings, and the code worked as expected. In Visual Studio 2008 however I got a compile time error saying 'operator= must return a value'.

My question is this: is this 'feature' apart of the core C++ language or is it something that the VS team decided to add in.

I do apologize if this has been asked or there is information on this online, I was unable to find any answers.

```
template <typename T>
struct singleton
{
T value;

singleton(const singleton& x) : value(x.value) {}
singleton() {}
~singleton() {}
singleton& operator=(const singleton& x) { value = x.value; }
};
```

This was the code I used for testing:

```
singleton<float> sf;
sf.value = 1.9f;
singleton<float> sf2 = sf;
std::cout << sf2.value << std::endl;
```

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: You have `singleton&` as the return value but return nothing.

Comment: @Rapptz I know, but it seems to be legal in VS2012 even with warning level 4

Comment: Have you actually instantiated / used this template?

Comment: I feel silly now, when I tested I used the copy constructor not the assignment operator. I forgot about template functions aren't instantiated unless they're used. Sorry! I'll make sure to do rigorous testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, your issue comes from your function returning `singleton&` however you don't actually return anything (i.e. `*this`). The standard considers this to be undefined behaviour.

Section 6.6.3.2

> Flowing oﬀ the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no
>   value; this results in undeﬁned behavior in a value-returning function

Comment: Thanks, I understand I just thought it was weird that I didn't receive any warnings/errors.

Comment: It might be worth noting that AFAIK, the assignment operator doesn't *need* to return anything. It can be a `void` method. However, that would disable usages like `a = b = c = d;`

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined behavior for a function returning non-void to have an absent return value. It may be allowed but it doesn't mean it's Standard-conformant.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would be nice minimalist code, just wanted to check what the standard said about this.